# Does not need ScrollView for entire layout in Android

Tags: android, scrollview, android-relativelayout

I have a `RelativeLayout` with mulitple tables and as well as some headers, my problem is that I do not want entire layout to be scrollable instead of that I need to scroll only the tables.

Below is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:myapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.test"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"

       android:fillViewport="true"
       android:scrollbarSize="12dip"
       android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset"
       android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
       android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="true">  


<RelativeLayout 

    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Headerdash"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="Welcome:"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tableheader"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" >
    </TextView>

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tableheader"
        android:layout_marginTop="9dip" >

        <TableRow android:gravity="right" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/refreshmain"
                android:layout_width="64dip"
                android:layout_height="22dip"
                android:autoLink="web"
                android:background="@drawable/search_button"
                android:linksClickable="true"
                android:text="Refresh"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dip"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:text="|"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/moremain"
                android:layout_width="53dip"
                android:layout_height="22dip"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:autoLink="web"
                android:background="@drawable/search_button"
                android:linksClickable="true"
                android:text="Home"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>



    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Header"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dip" >
    </ListView>

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/table1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="140dip"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tableheader"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
        android:background="@drawable/shape"
        android:shrinkColumns="*"
        android:stretchColumns="*" >

        <!-- Row 1 with single column -->

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_span="3"
                android:text="Vehicles"
                android:textColor="#005D90"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_span="3"
                android:text="Moving"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="14dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_span="3"
                android:text="Stopped"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="14dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_span="3"
                android:text="Idling"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="14dp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/vehicle1"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_span="3"
                android:text="1"
                android:textColor="#005D90"
                android:textSize="35dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_span="3"
                android:id="@+id/vehicle2"
                android:text="2"
                android:textColor="#005D90"
                android:textSize="35dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_span="3"
                android:id="@+id/vehicle3"
                android:text="3"
                android:textColor="#005D90"
                android:textSize="35dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/table2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="140dip"
        android:layout_below="@+id/table1"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
        android:background="@drawable/shape"
        android:shrinkColumns="*"
        android:stretchColumns="*" >

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_span="3"
                android:text="Speeding"
                android:textColor="#005D90"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_span="3"
                android:text="&lt;30km"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="14dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_span="3"
                android:text=">30-60km"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="14dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_span="3"
                android:text=">60km"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="14dp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_span="3"
                android:text="1"
                android:id="@+id/speeding1"
                android:textColor="#005D90"
                android:textSize="35dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_span="3"
                 android:id="@+id/speeding2"
                android:text="2"
                android:textColor="#005D90"
                android:textSize="35dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_span="3"
                android:text="3"
                android:id="@+id/speeding3"
                android:textColor="#005D90"
                android:textSize="35dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/table3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="140dip"
        android:layout_below="@+id/table2"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
        android:background="@drawable/shape"
        android:shrinkColumns="*"
        android:stretchColumns="*" >

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_span="3"
                android:text="Odometer"
                android:textColor="#005D90"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_span="3"
                android:text="&lt;1000km"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="14dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_span="3"
                android:text=">1000km"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="14dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_span="3"
                android:text=">2000km"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="14dp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_span="3"
                android:text="1"
                 android:id="@+id/odometer1"
                android:textSize="35dip"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#005D90"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_span="3"
                android:text="2"
                android:id="@+id/odometer2"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#005D90"
                android:textSize="35dp"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_span="3"
                android:text="3"
                android:id="@+id/odometer3"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#005D90"
                android:textSize="35dp"
               />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

As per the layout above , its scrollable to entire layout , but instead of that i need to scroll only the `TableLayout` I created above.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You shouldn't have a `ListView` inside a `ScrollView`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this one

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Headerdash"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
    android:text="Welcome:"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="14dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" >
</TextView>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="true"
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
    android:scrollbarSize="12dip"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/tableheader"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="9dip" >

            <TableRow android:gravity="right" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/refreshmain"
                    android:layout_width="64dip"
                    android:layout_height="22dip"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2dip"
                    android:autoLink="web"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:linksClickable="true"
                    android:text="Refresh"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:text="|"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/moremain"
                    android:layout_width="53dip"
                    android:layout_height="22dip"
                    android:autoLink="web"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:linksClickable="true"
                    android:text="Home"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/Header"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dip"
            android:visibility="gone" >
        </ListView>

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/table1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="140dip"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tableheader"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:shrinkColumns="*"
            android:stretchColumns="*" >

            <!-- Row 1 with single column -->

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_span="3"
                    android:text="Vehicles"
                    android:textColor="#005D90"
                    android:textSize="18dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_span="3"
                    android:text="Moving"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textSize="14dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_span="3"
                    android:text="Stopped"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textSize="14dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_span="3"
                    android:text="Idling"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textSize="14dp" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/vehicle1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_span="3"
                    android:text="1"
                    android:textColor="#005D90"
                    android:textSize="35dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/vehicle2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_span="3"
                    android:text="2"
                    android:textColor="#005D90"
                    android:textSize="35dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/vehicle3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_span="3"
                    android:text="3"
                    android:textColor="#005D90"
                    android:textSize="35dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/table2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="140dip"
            android:layout_below="@+id/table1"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:shrinkColumns="*"
            android:stretchColumns="*" >

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_span="3"
                    android:text="Speeding"
                    android:textColor="#005D90"
                    android:textSize="18dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_span="3"
                    android:text="&lt;30km"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textSize="14dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_span="3"
                    android:text=">30-60km"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textSize="14dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_span="3"
                    android:text=">60km"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textSize="14dp" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/speeding1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_span="3"
                    android:text="1"
                    android:textColor="#005D90"
                    android:textSize="35dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/speeding2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_span="3"
                    android:text="2"
                    android:textColor="#005D90"
                    android:textSize="35dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/speeding3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_span="3"
                    android:text="3"
                    android:textColor="#005D90"
                    android:textSize="35dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/table3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="140dip"
            android:layout_below="@+id/table2"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:shrinkColumns="*"
            android:stretchColumns="*" >

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_span="3"
                    android:text="Odometer"
                    android:textColor="#005D90"
                    android:textSize="18dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_span="3"
                    android:text="&lt;1000km"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textSize="14dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_span="3"
                    android:text=">1000km"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textSize="14dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_span="3"
                    android:text=">2000km"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textSize="14dp" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/odometer1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_span="3"
                    android:text="1"
                    android:textColor="#005D90"
                    android:textSize="35dip"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/odometer2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_span="3"
                    android:text="2"
                    android:textColor="#005D90"
                    android:textSize="35dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/odometer3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_span="3"
                    android:text="3"
                    android:textColor="#005D90"
                    android:textSize="35dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the response, I need to have scrollable for all the tables i specified above not for one table.

Comment: same method follow for all table i show with one layout and  u cant remove list view which sandwich with two table layout so different scroll need for all table layout

Comment: Sorry , I used scrollview for all the tables. I am unable to get that view. Please suggest one Scrollview for all the table layout if possible

Comment: means u want only one scroll in which all table layout include

Comment: Please wait dude I ll let you know..Thanks